# How To Get Laravel 5.8 Pagination To Work With Angular 8

Tags: angular, laravel, eloquent, pagination

Am having problems getting the next set of results from the database using laravel pagination.
My results looks like this from this route:  api/getMerchants

```
{
    "merchants": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [], // contains some data
        "first_page_url": "/?page=1",
        "from": null,
        "next_page_url": "/?page=2",
        "path": "/",
        "per_page": 15,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": null
    }
}
```

Now when I try to get the next set of results by calling the route which is api/getMerchants and appending the next page url value to it, i get the same set of result but this time only the current_page value changes to 2 and the next_page_url changes to 3. The final url looks like this:

```
api/getMerchants/?page=2
```

What am i doing wrong ? How do i get the next set of results, i get the same thing when i try in postman as well.

This is my controller:

```
public function getMerchants(Request $request){

        //get all registered companies 
        $getmerchants = DB::table('merchants')
        ->join('joint_companies', 'joint_companies.id', '=', 'super_id')
        ->join('company_admin', 'company_admin.id', '=', 'admin_id')
        ->select('merchants.*','company_admin.name AS admin_name','joint_companies.name AS exec_name')
        ->get();

        //clean data
        $merchantsdata = [];

        $merchants = $getmerchants->map(function($items){
            $merchantsdata['id'] = $items->id;
            $merchantsdata['merchant_name'] = Crypt::decryptString($items->merchant_name);
            $merchantsdata['status'] = $items->status;
            $merchantsdata['country'] = $items->country;
            $merchantsdata['logo'] = $items->logo;

            return $merchantsdata;
         });

         $objects = new Paginator($merchants, 15);
         $response = [
            'merchants' => $objects
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 200);

    }
```

Comment: it is looks like you have bug on your `laravel` implementation, you should post your `eloquant` and `controller` to have chance to be helped.

Comment: @Yanis-git i just edited the question to show my controller

Comment: Hope you are finding this : https://youtu.be/VnEgCk-MlN4

Answer (score 0):

By calling `DB::table('merchants') ... ->get()` you are not using the `Paginator` component.

As you can see on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results) you should call `->paginate()`:

```
    //get all registered companies 
    $marchands = DB::table('merchants')
    ->join('joint_companies', 'joint_companies.id', '=', 'super_id')
    ->join('company_admin', 'company_admin.id', '=', 'admin_id')
    ->select('merchants.*','company_admin.name AS admin_name','joint_companies.name AS exec_name')
    ->paginate();
```

Pay attention `$marchands` is now `Paginator` object

you probably still want to transform your data collection by doing :

```
$marchands->getCollection()->transform(function ($marchand) {
     $marchand->merchant_name = Crypt::decryptString($marchand->merchant_name);
     return $marchand;
});
```

Paginator class implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable` you can give the object to your response or call `$marchands->toJson()`

Comment: How do you return the transformed data

Comment: i have update my answser. actually `transform` mutate the original object instead of returning a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error. To solve this you need to notify that how many items have in your database table? if the item is 2 and your per_page value is 5 then you can get only one page data. Now if you hit the request with page = 2 (for second page), then how can you get the second page data. Naturally it will show your empty data. And your query has been showed that.